# why the TCP receiver can receive data after the Socket Server has shut down?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, io

I am using Java to implement a multithreaded TCP server-client application. But now i have encountered a strange problem: when i shutdown the server socket, the receiver can still receives the last sent packet continuously. Since the detail of socket read is of the kernel concern, i can't figure out the reason. Can anybody give some guideline? 
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
The code involved is simple:

```
public void run() {
  while(runFlag) {
      //in = socket.getSocketInputStream();
      //byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; 
      try {
          in.read(buffer);
          //process the buffer;
      }catch(IOException e) {
          //
      }
  }
}
```

when shutdown the server socket, this read operation will receive packet continuously(each time enters the while loop).

Answer (score 3):

The TCP/IP stack inside the OS is *buffering* the data on both sides of the connection. Sender fills its *socket send buffer*, which is drained by the device driver pushing packets onto the wire. Receiver accumulates packets off the wire in the *socket receive buffer*, which is drained by the application reads.

Comment: Thank you @ThiefMaster, @Nikolai N Fetissov for your quick and helpful response. It seems that the problem occurred in the buffer of the client. But i am still not very sure about why.(why in.read(buffer) don't consume the kernel buffer?)

Comment: The connection would be half-open which is a valid state.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is already in the client socket's buffer (kernel-level, waiting for your application to read it into userspace memory), there is no way for the server to prevent it from being read. It's like with snail mail: once you've sent it away you cannot undo it.

Comment: If the data is already in the *sender's* socket buffer it will still be sent ahead of the FIN.

Comment: It is a *single bit* indicating that this is the final packet for this connection.

Answer (score 0):

That's how TCP works. It's a reliable byte-stream. Undelivered data continues to be delivered after a normal close. Isn't that what you want? Why is this a 'problem'?

Comment: I'm sorry if i didn't make it clear. By 'problem', i mean the read operation of the client will succeed in reading the last sent packets constantly(I think it makes sense to block on reading or throw an exception rather than get the same packets every time). I have edited my question, maybe you can give it a look.

Comment: The error there is that you are ignoring the result of in.read(). If it returns -1 the peer has closed the connection, so you must close the socket and exit the loop. You are also ignoring the possibility that the buffer isn't full, which would be indicated by a positive return value from read() less than buffer.length, so your code won't work anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really helpful. It's my fault to ignore the return value of read(). But what i tried to do is to make use of the exception thrown by read() for indication of the network state and to control the work flow of the program. According to java API docs,  read() will return -1 if the end of stream is detected and throw IOException "If the first byte cannot be read for any reason  other than the end of the file, if the input stream has been closed, or if some other I/O error occurs".  Why this read() in my code doesn't thrown any exception if i shutdown the server?

Comment: Because it returned -1, indicating that the end of the stream was detected.

Comment: @Xu DXn: "End of file" is what happens when the server shuts down, so there is no exception - just a -1 return value.